# Django allauth custom social account provider doesn't activate

Tags: django, allauth, socialaccount

I've installed django allauth with social providers, and it works.
Now I've created a custom social account provider based on Microsoft Graph, just creating a new app, added code from socialaccounts/providers/microsoft and changed adapter and provider classes names to my own, as well as the provider id.
Now it shows on the login/signup pages but when I click on it to be redirected to microsoft's authentication page it doesn't work and goes back to login page, without errors.

How to fix it to let my custom social account provider to be working?